How can I fix the validation error when adding a file?
I work with laravel and cms orchid. Why a validation error occurs when adding a file via the upload component.
  Layout::rows([
                 Select::make('user_id')
                     ->value($this->orders->user_id)
                     ->fromModel(User::class, 'familia'),
 
                 Upload::make('file')->maxFiles(1)->maxFileSize(50)
                     ->title('Файл для вывода')->acceptedFiles('.pdf,.doc,.docx,.txt'),
 
             ]);

Message of error: Validation error. File upload error.

Code php.ini
post_max_size                = 50M
upload_max_filesize          = 50M

Code file config/filesystem.php
   'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            //'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

How to defeat a mistake?

Check for the logs for what the reason the error occured.

@xenooooo, There is only an error message in the log file when I tried to explicitly set the file limit sizes: "Cannot set the desired maximum file size. This contradicts the settings specified in .ini" I'm talking about this construction "->maxFileSize(50)".

check your php.ini and config/filesystems.php are configured correctly or not.
in you php.ini file upload_max_filesize & post_max_size should be 50M or greater
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M

in your config/filesystems.php file follow this configuration
'disks' => [
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],

I hope this will solve your problem.

configures correctly php.ini. In the file .env connecting this file system.  APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://lucky-time.loc/public/
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=public
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120. Did I connect it correctly?

I have two projects on laravel orchid. One works by uploading images and files. Not in the other one. Both projects are on OpenServer, respectively, the configuration of the web server is correct.

php.ini and config/filesystems.php these are not the configure of .env file
if you are linux based user find your php.ini file like this one /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php. ini 
and config/filesystems.php this one find out from your project directory yourProject/config/filesystems.php
update above code inside these two file

I made such settings in php.ini and config/filesystems.php but the problem remains.

added code and comments to the question

The error lies in the fact that the address in the browser's address bar differs from the one specified in the settings.
The framework's developers state that they do not support and do not plan to support installation in a subdirectory.
If you are an experienced user, you might attempt to resolve this using configuration files (this was previously possible for Mix, but I haven't tried it with Vite). However, such solutions do not guarantee proper functionality or support in the future.
The best option would be to set up the environment according to the framework's requirements.
